# Can I programmatically add event handler to a ListView or other compoent using refs in react-native?

Tags: react-native

Can you programmatically add an event handler to a component via a ref? This throws an error saying addEventListener is not a function:

```
this.refs.myListView.addEventListener('onContentSizeChange', () => {...});
```

The **onContentSizeChange** event is triggered A LOT so I only want to attach a handler to it when needed, which is why I don't want to do it on the component declaration in the render function. I want to be able to programmatically attached and detach as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method `addEventListener` in ListView component. Thats the reason for the error message.

If you want to subscribe to `onContentSizeChange` event then you will have to use `onContentSizeChange` props on render function. You cannot dynamically attach or detach listener.

For reference here is the code from ListView.js

```
 _onContentSizeChange: function(width: number, height: number) {
    var contentLength = !this.props.horizontal ? height : width;
    if (contentLength !== this.scrollProperties.contentLength) {
      this.scrollProperties.contentLength = contentLength;
      this._updateVisibleRows();
      this._renderMoreRowsIfNeeded();
    }
    this.props.onContentSizeChange && this.props.onContentSizeChange(width, height);
  }
```

In the last line you can see that only if `this.props.onContentSizeChange` is set then callback will be called and in React props are immutable.